# How to return a result properly from async/await function?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, async-await

I have worked with async/await functions for a few months now and I have gotten all my code to work, however, I don't understand it completely and could use some words of wisdom.

In my code below I have an async function, my question is... why does it return a promise instead of the value I expect? And more importantly, what is the proper way to get the value I want?

```
  getName = async () => {
    const request = await fetch(apiUrl)
    const data = await request.json()

    return data.response.name
  }
```

I call the function later

`const name = getName()`

But `name` is then a promise instead of the name.

I have looked this up many times and it never sticks. I am hoping using my own example if someone can explain it to me so I understand completely it will finally stick with me.

***EDIT*** - In response to @Paulpro I have updated my question to below...

Assuming the async function is okay, the question is, how do I store the value.

```
const name = getName()
```

'name' is now a promise, so I normally do something like this...

```
getName().then(name => setName(name))
```

but how do I make const name === the returned name?

Comment: You're already doing it the proper way. JavaScript functions return synchronously, so you can't return a value that is obtained asynchronously; that would be time travel. The best you can do is return a Promise.

Comment: You cant syncly assign from async code and be able to use it immediatly. You have do it and use it in some callback or use the assignment in another async function and `await` it, eg `name = await getName()`

Comment: i guess you cant use like that(the way you wanted) , you want it to behave like a sync function, but unfortunately its a async one. so cant break the inbuilt rule i guess.

Comment: asynchrony (no matter if using async/await or not) is like a virus. Once you use it (and you have to for asynchronous tasks like AJAX for example) it *infects* all the code that uses it - you can't *cure* it, you just have to live with it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> how do I make const name === the returned name?

By using `const name = await getName()`.

Which means you have to use it inside an `async` function.

So your approach using:

```
getName().then(name => setName(name))
```

is most likely the best way to do it, but it really depends on the the rest of your code.

I mean you could do it like this:

```
let name;

getName = async () => {
  const request = await fetch(apiUrl)
  const data = await request.json()

  name = data.response.name;
}
```

When (and if) both of your async requests finish, your `name` variable will have the result. But there is no guarantee on the timing of that. Depending on the app, it might be fine if you initialize your variable like this:

```
let name = 'Loading...';
```

Comment: Ok - I 'get' all of your answers. I think you are right that the one with ```getName().then(name => setName(name))``` is appropriate because putting it in the async function would create a side effect. This way ```getName``` stays a pure function that can be used in other places and the response can be handled outside the function. (I wish I had confidence in the validity of what I just said - lol)

Comment: Actually, I just realized my ```getName()``` function cannot be a pure function because it is making an API call which it has no control over. However, it at least will not be mutating any outside variables, which is what I was aiming for. I put everything in a try/catch so that it either returns the 'name' value or an 'error' message.

Comment: @Ronald yeah, better to not mutate outside variables inside your `getName()` function which should stay true to its name, and just get the name and return it. You sound like you're thinking pretty clearly about code quality.

Comment: You can also use await again, E.G. `setName( await getName( ) )`, but that needs to be in another `async` function since you can't use await outside of one. That's usually what you want anyway though.

Comment: or if you want name to be in a const: `const name = await getName( );`.

Comment: @Ronald Either way you don't need to modify getName and you're correct that you should not assign to a free variable inside getName.