# Argument of type 'void' is not assignable to parameter of type 'SetStateAction<never[]>'

Tags: javascript, typescript, react-native

I am getting the following error:

```
Argument of type 'void' is not assignable to parameter of type 'SetStateAction<never[]>'.
```

My relevant code looks like this:

```
const ViewEvents: React.FC<ViewEventsProps> = ({ navigation }) => {

const flatListRef = useRef(null);
const [limit] = useState(5);
const [page, setPage] = useState(1);
const [clientData, setClientData] = useState([]);
const [serverData, serverDataLoaded] = useState([]);
const [pending_process, setPending_process] = useState(true);
const [loadmore, setLoadmore] = useState(false);
const [refresh, setRefresh] = useState(false);

const getEvents = async (thePage: any) => {
    try {
        const value = await AsyncStorage.getItem('user_id');
        if (value !== null) {
            // We have data!!
            const user_id = JSON.parse(value)
            const response = await APIKit.get('/v1/events/user-events/' + user_id)
                .then((response) => {
                    console.log(response.data)
                    return response.data.slice((thePage - 1) * limit, thePage * limit);
                }, (error) => {
                    console.log(error);
                });
        }
    } catch (error) {
        // Error retrieving data
    }
}

const requestToServer = async (thePage: any) => {
    let data = await getEvents(thePage);
    console.log('data', data);
    serverDataLoaded(data);
};
```

Obviously data is not being initialized with the data returned from the getEvents function. What I cannot figure out is why? I am using TypeScript and so far no errors are being thrown from the getEvents function.

I am new to React and TypeScript so I might be missing something and so far all the similar questions I have seen online do not seem to be relevant to my error.

Comment: Yes. That’s the line that’s throwing the error

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all let's look at `SetStateAction<never[]>`. If you hover over `serverData` in this line:

```
const [serverData, serverDataLoaded] = useState([]);
```

It will tell you the type of `serverData` is `never[]`. The problem is that `[]` is not enough information for typescript to know what should into that array, since there is no contents to infer types from. To do that you need to pass in a type parameter to `useState`.

I dont know the shape of your data, but something like:

```
const [serverData, serverDataLoaded] =
  useState<{ id: number, name: string }[]>([]);
```

Now if you hover over `serverData` you should see:

```
const serverData: {
    id: number;
    name: string;
}[]
```

And if you hover over `serverDataLoaded` you should see:

```
const serverDataLoaded: React.Dispatch<React.SetStateAction<{
    id: number;
    name: string;
}[]>>
```

So now that function is a React set state action that takes the type you defined.

---

Now let's look at the other side of your problem: Why is that value you're trying to assign `void`?.

If you hover over `getEvents`, you should see the inferred return type of that function. You should see this:

```
const getEvents: (thePage: any) => Promise<void>
```

So typescript believes that the function returns a promise, that resolve to `void`. That means that typescript didn't see a return statement in your function.

Why is that? Well, the only return statement is in a nested function. You seem to have mixed up `async/await` and the promise based `.then()` style. You should never use *both* of these. In this case you only need to `await` the call to the api, and then use whatever it returned:

```
const response = await APIKit.get('/v1/events/user-events/' + user_id)
console.log(response.data)
return response.data.slice((thePage - 1) * limit, thePage * limit);
```

Now that `return` statement is hit in the normal function flow, and now in a nested function.

See: [How to return a result properly from async/await function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55876386/how-to-return-a-result-properly-from-async-await-function) for more information on this.

---

Now, after all that, `getEvents` returns a value instead of `void`, and `serverData` and `serverDataLoaded` both have the right types, and it should work as you expect.

[See typescript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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-PgQI0mPioAB9PZMXU+n3ASiNANB+QAQmKpWl6XSyK9ubrbjgAHV5LEcPo4BNcCWS666xU-cR5ZmxiU4AApTAAeQAcqEwDgoBhC4Hg18+7mB6xUJA8iG6mGIwFgmEIinLLoDpZ0HCEZY0xprybb88ANSDjN7Nfr73UiCZULpBAMiNFuO4YKEnY4F+36VKwMAtGIcCgQa6AQZMoSoFi7DoI0jTWrachwBocAHMiABUcBYiAIREPhThwBRVEhDm34-HWNDsHg7CxE08r0FANa9t6DbQlA-FIfGnTXmqkFCWxlQ-JSm7oAAjsGZg3BAmDygyo4WlasQ2nadQOksKK5pk8CQXpB7wEaN6InRcgsT6v7-oBwFMJBTBEJBLnemy8ocjg3K8vyjR+RSaw-FQQA)

Comment: Thanks so much for the detailed explanation. I was able to solve the issue with the suggestions you gave. I am going to head back to the documentation to get a better understanding of the useState feature because I think that is my biggest misunderstanding.

Answer (score 1):

Debug your execution of `getEvents` function where you have mixed up both `async` `await` and `.then` handling of `promise`